# angular 1 json pipe causing Lexer Error: Unterminated quote

Tags: angularjs

I'm displaying data in json format using angular1's json pipe:

```
<pre>{{myJSONData | json}}</pre>
```

`myJSONData` contains single quotes. For example:

```
{"info": "Info about Men's and Womens Shoes"}
```

I get this parsing error:

```
angular.js:14199 Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 732-749 ["Info about ] in expression...
```

Looks like the single quotes cause the error.

But, I cannot manually escape the single quotes because I don't know what the data looks like.

I simply get the data from an api call and display it.

Comment: "Allows you to convert a JavaScript object into JSON string. This filter is mostly useful for debugging. When using the double curly notation the binding is automatically converted to JSON." -- sure this is the correct filter?

Comment: json pipe formats and beautifies json data which is why I chose it.